# Buildozer java erro

Tags: java, python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am new to kivy and buildozer both. Also I am running buildozer for the very first time to build application for android. I programmed an application which works fine on python interpreter without any errors. So I went on converting the code into an application for android since kivy is a cross-platform programming language but when i started buildozer to make application i get a weird type of error and as i am new i dont know whats the solution so please help me! 
After Installing buildozer i just made a .spec file and started debugging without editing the .spec file so as to test that everything is fine or not and on running buildozer it downloaded the sdk and ndk and installed them but after installing them it gives a long error whose log i have given below so see it and please help at your earliest so that i can learn and get more out of kivy.
Thank You In Advance

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Read available permissions from api-versions.xml
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.7 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Run 'git config --get remote.origin.url'
# Cwd /root/Documents/CoronaKivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android.git
# Run 'git branch -vv'
# Cwd /root/Documents/CoronaKivy/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
* master 8cf66cc1 [origin/master] Merge pull request #2111 from kivy/release-2020.03.30
# Run '/usr/bin/python3.7 -m pip install -q --user \'appdirs\' \'colorama>=0.3.3\' \'jinja2\' \'six\' \'enum34; python_version<"3.4"\' \'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"\' \'pep517<0.7.0"\' \'pytoml\' \'virtualenv<20\''
# Cwd None
# Apache ANT found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4
# Android SDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
# Recommended android's NDK version by p4a is: 19b
# Android NDK found at /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b
# Installing/updating SDK platform tools if necessary
# Run '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools'
# Cwd /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
# Command failed: /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager tools platform-tools
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/kali:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1329,unix/kali:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1329'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IN:en'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/0/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'gnome'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1282'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     DBUS_STARTER_BUS_TYPE = 'session'
#     PWD = '/root/Documents/CoronaKivy'
#     LOGNAME = 'root'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'gnome'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'qt5ct'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/0/gdm/Xauthority'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_IN'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     USERNAME = 'root'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_IN'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6000'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/a738ed9c_93c5_47ac_8f3a_19686d6ae6bd'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '03fd0c25e1254af3adc502f37fccdaac'
#     MANAGERPID = '1136'
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     USER = 'root'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.236'
#     DISPLAY = ':1'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     DBUS_STARTER_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/0/bus,guid=d7f786b64d6c4a995f2f8dbc5e8af503'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/0'
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '9:29874'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'gnome'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/0/bus,guid=d7f786b64d6c4a995f2f8dbc5e8af503'
#     _JAVA_OPTIONS = '-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on -Dswing.aatext=true'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Comment: You may try to select a better title by which one can understand the full story (your app is not known by someone who is searching for his/her same problem).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue . The problem was that I was not using the correct java version.
I was using jdk-11 ,but I had to use OpenJDK-8-jdk. 
Please check your java version with the command

```
java -version
```

That will show you the java version. Now when It doesn´t show "OpenJDK version 1.8.0_242"
Consider installing it using

```
sudo apt install -y git zip unzip openjdk-8-jdk
```

When you want to switch through java versions. Use the command

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Please tell me if that worked